# The button press count program in espressif ide using esp32c3 development board doesn't show the press count

Tags: button, esp32, espressif-idf

```
// task that will react to button clicks
void button_task(void* arg) {

    // infinite loop
    for(;;) {

        // wait for the notification from the ISR
        if(xSemaphoreTake(xSemaphore,portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
            int buttonState = gpio_get_level(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0);

            //while(buttonState == 1){ //code stucks here!!!!
            while(gpio_get_level(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0)==1){
                buttonCount++;
                printf("GPIO_INPUT_IO_0 %d\n", buttonState);
                printf("Button pressed! %d \n", i++);
                gpio_set_level(BLINK_LED, buttonState);
                vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                }
        }
    }
}

void app_main()
{
    // create the binary semaphore
    xSemaphore = xSemaphoreCreateBinary();

    // configure button and led pins as GPIO pins
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0);
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(BLINK_LED);

    // set the correct direction
    gpio_set_direction(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(BLINK_LED, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    // enable interrupt on falling (1->0) edge for button pin
    gpio_set_intr_type(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0, GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE);

    // start the task that will handle the button
    xTaskCreate(button_task, "button_task", 2048, NULL, 10, NULL);

    // install ISR service with default configuration
    gpio_install_isr_service(ESP_INTR_FLAG_DEFAULT);

    // attach the interrupt service routine
    gpio_isr_handler_add(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0, button_isr_handler, NULL);

    int pass = 25;
    xTaskCreate(&printVariable, "printVariable", 2048, (void*) pass, 5, &printVariableTask);

}
```

The control flow doesn't enter into the while loop. I have tried changing the condition in the while loop statement ( the previous one was commented) but it didn't help.....can I know what is wrong with it? I am using espressif v5.0 and the development board that I am using is esp32-C3 and I connected the pin of the switch to GPIO 4 and dumped the code( the above code is not the whole code, I only posted the part where it is getting struck which is the while loop, it doesn't even enter into it ).

Comment: The code you posted does not look for a switch connected to GPIO4.

Answer (score 0):

```
void button_task(void* arg) {

    // infinite loop
    for(;;) {

        // wait for the notification from the ISR
        if(xSemaphoreTake(xSemaphore,portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
            int buttonState = gpio_get_level(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0);

            if(buttonState){ 
            //while(gpio_get_level(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0)){

                printf("GPIO_INPUT_IO_0 %d\n", buttonState);
                printf("Button pressed! %d \n", i++);
                gpio_set_level(BLINK_LED, buttonState);
                vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                }
            buttonCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

The above function in the code works!!!

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?